# jQuery stop click spamming

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, jquery-animate

I am using jQuery to make two image arrows to slide DIVs. I noticed that on click spamming the  DIVs' margins were completely messed and they couldn't get back to the defined positions. With some search I ended up with the following code:

```
var is_clicked = false;
    $("#arrow_r").click(function(){
        if (is_clicked == true){
            return;
        }
        is_clicked = true;
        var $img_block = $('.photoBlock:visible');//current
        if ($img_block.next().length > 0){
            $img_block.animate({
                    marginLeft:-$('#server_photo_listing').outerWidth()
                },function(){
                    is_clicked = true;
                    var $img_block = $('.photoBlock:visible');//current
                    var $img_block_next = $img_block.next();//next
                    $img_block.css("display","none");
                    $img_block_next.css("display","inherit");
                    $img_block_next.animate({
                        marginLeft:0
                    }
                    );
                    is_clicked = false;
                  });
        }

    });

    $("#arrow_l").click(function(){
        if (is_clicked == true){
            return;
        }
        is_clicked = true;
        var $img_block = $('.photoBlock:visible');//current
        if ($img_block.prev().length > 0){
            $img_block.animate({
                    marginLeft:$('#server_photo_listing').outerWidth() 
                }, function(){
                    is_clicked = true;
                    var $img_block = $('.photoBlock:visible');//current
                    var $img_block_prev = $img_block.prev();//previous
                    $img_block.css("display","none");
                    $img_block_prev.css("display","inherit");
                    $img_block_prev.animate({
                        marginLeft:0
                    }
                    );
                    is_clicked = false;
                  });
        }
    });
```

Although it worked OK initially for the one arrow when I used it on the second also, after some click spamming testing the variable `is_clicked` remains `true` so the sliding stops.

I have to say also that the arrows are also used in a different DIV which is on `display:none` - in case it has any importance. Also, all the above code include more functions are inside a main `$(function(){});` - again, if it has any importance.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would start by consolidating those handlers into a single handler - they are nearly identical.

Answer (score 0):

you can bind and unbind clack event on this element.

first create 2 functions, at the event you unbind the click event and where your animation is finished you rebind the event.

```
var go_right = function(){
    $("#arrow_r").unbind('click');
    var $img_block = $('.photoBlock:visible');//current
    if ($img_block.next().length > 0){
        $img_block.animate({
            marginLeft:-$('#server_photo_listing').outerWidth()
        },function(){
            var $img_block = $('.photoBlock:visible');//current
            var $img_block_next = $img_block.next();//next
            $img_block.css("display","none");
            $img_block_next.css("display","inherit");
            $img_block_next.animate({
                marginLeft:0
            }, function () {
                $("#arrow_r").bind('click', go_right);
            });
        });
    }
};
var go_left = function(){
    $("#arrow_l").unbind('click');
    var $img_block = $('.photoBlock:visible');//current
    if ($img_block.prev().length > 0){
        $img_block.animate({
        marginLeft:$('#server_photo_listing').outerWidth() 
        }, function(){
            var $img_block = $('.photoBlock:visible');//current
            var $img_block_prev = $img_block.prev();//previous
            $img_block.css("display","none");
            $img_block_prev.css("display","inherit");
            $img_block_prev.animate({
                marginLeft:0
            }, function () {
                $("#arrow_l").bind('click', go_left);
            });
        });
    }
};

$("#arrow_r").bind('click', go_right);
$("#arrow_l").bind('click', go_left);
```

Hope that help you

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I have the same result. When I spam clicking on one of the arrows after a while both stop working.